# Build configuration WebApp with Git & grunt

Tags: git, gruntjs, webstorm

In my webapp project I have 4 infos: they change when I'm developing or deploying.

- serverAddres: the backend where my app send the ajax calls
- serverPort: the port of backend
- clientVersion: the version of my client webapp
- deployPath: the pat in an apache server where I want deploy the app

I use GIT to manage the sourcecode and Grunt to automatize the deploy process.

I have more backend server (id/port couples) for example one in production and one in test.

In my apache server I have more paths where I can deploy the application, for example a production path and a test path.

Now the 4 infos are written in different files:

clientVersion and deployPath are in package.json grunt file.
serverAddress and serverPort are in another file.

The problem is that the 2 files are monitored by GIT and when I merge the branches I overwrite the infos.

What I would like is to have a fixed set of configuration options, monitored by Git but indipendent from the current branch. What is the right way to manage the build configuration developing a webapp?

Usually I run the app in my IDE by set serverAddress and serverPort. Then, when I want deploy on apache server the app I set the clientVersion and serverPort and run the grnt task.

Comment: I have tried to config grunt-prompt [link](https://github.com/dylang/grunt-prompt)   to automatize the build task but it not work in my IDE (Webstorm)

Comment: Could you add more information (framework, coutinious-integration & deployment tools, project structure), please?